# Why is $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{1-\cos(x)} $ not equal to 0?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, solution-verification, limits-without-lhopital

I was watching Calculus 1 lectures on Youtube, particularly Professor Leonard's, and I thought I would be able to answer a question on the board very simply, but I've reached quite an odd answer and I can't identify the faulty logic in my way of solving. Here is the question and my steps to solve it:

Evaluate: $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{1-\cos(x)} $$

My approach to solving this was to take $ x $ out as a factor, then deal with the two expressions as two limits, and eventually treat the latter as a reciprocal of the fundamental $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x}= 0$ 
Steps:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \left[x \cdot \frac{x}{1-\cos(x)}\right] $$
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} x \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{1-\cos(x)} $$
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} x \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}\right)^{-1} $$
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} x \cdot \left[\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}\right]^{-1} $$
$$ 0 \cdot 0^{-1} = 0 $$

Now I am aware that my answer is mathematically wrong and that the correct limit is 2, but I can't deduce why by using my current knowledge of calculus. I would appreciate it if someone pointed out the reason I can not evaluate this limit this way.

Comment: Reciprocal of $0$ is not defined in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Only finite limits factor in the manner you assumed.

Comment: $0^{-1}$, presumably, means the multiplicative inverse of $0$, which if it existed would be a real number $x$ having the property that $0 \cdot x = 1$. Such a number does not exist, because $0 \cdot x = 0$ for all real numbers $x$.

Comment: "My approach to solving this was to take x out as a factor, then deal with the two expressions as two limits"  You can not *EVER* do that.  *EVER*.  It's a rookie mistake but the values of $x$ and the values of $1-\cos x$ are not independent.  If you look at the behavior of $x$ and $1-\cos x$ where $x$ is near zero you can't consider the behavior and nearness of one without also considering the behavior and nearness of the other.  So you can not considered there limits separately.

Comment: As of yet, you have 6 answers to your question which is quite a lot. Please select one or give feedback why they are not satisfactory. Questions should not just stay open forever.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking the "intuitive" rules for calculating limits such as

$$
\lim f(x)g(x)=\lim f(x) \cdot\lim g(x)
$$
do only work if all limits exist. This is not the case here since the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x}{1-\cos(x)}
$$
does not exist.
That being said if you extend the real numbers with plus and minus infinity you can also extend the rules to some more cases e.g. $\infty \cdot a=\infty$ for $a\neq0$. However that is not the case for your specific example which reads $0\cdot\infty$ which is often referred to as "indeterminate form".

Please refer to the chapter "properties" in the following link:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function

Answer (score 3):

Note that $1-\cos(x)=2\sin^2(x/2)$, so
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{1-\cos(x)}
&=\frac{x^2}{2\sin^2(x/2)}\\
&=\frac{4\,(x/2)^2}{2\sin^2(x/2)}\\
&=2\left(\frac{x/2}{\sin(x/2)}\right)^2
\end{align}
$$
Now we can apply $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is ***NOT*** an answer in any rigorous form, but plotting the graph of the given function can offer some intuition as well-after you have dealt with the calculus (or if to your best efforts you didn't manage to deal with it).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$0/0$ is indeterminate.  Use L'Hospital's rule:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{1-\cos x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x}{\sin x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2}{\cos x} = \frac{2}{\cos 0} = 2$$

Comment: I believe that's the right approach, but I haven't reached L'Hospital's rule yet in the course. However, Professor Leonard and my professor both multiply by conjugates and go from there to also reach 2. But, I am more interested in why my steps of evaluating are not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is the "series" method.  As $x \to 0$, we have
$$
\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2)
\\
1 - \cos x = \frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2)
\\
\frac{x^2}{1 - \cos x} = \frac{x^2}{\frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2)}
=  \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2} + o(1)} \rightarrow 2
$$

Answer (score -1):

"My approach to solving this was to take x out as a factor, then deal with the two expressions as two limits"

You can not *EVER* do that.  *EVER*.  It's a rookie mistake but the values of $x$ and the values of $1-\cos x$ are not independent.

If you look at the behavior of $x^2$ and $1-\cos x$ where $x$ is near zero you can't consider the behavior and nearness of one without also considering the behavior and nearness of the other.  So you can not considered thir limits separately.

Here is an example of way it doesn't work.

Take $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {x}{2x}$. If you consider the limits separately you can try "doing the denominator first".  SO as $x \to 0$ we have $\frac {x}{2x}\to \frac 0{2x} = 0$. Then *after* we do that we consider $2x\to 0$ we get $\frac 0{2x} = 0$ cosistantly so $0\to 0$ as $2x\to 0$.  So $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac x{2x}= \lim_{\color{green}x\to 0}\lim_{\color{red}x \to 0}\frac {\color{red}x}{\color{green}{2x}}=\lim_{\color{green}x \to 0}\frac 0{2x}=\lim_{\color{green}x \to 0} 0 = 0$.

Or we not $2x \to 0$ and we do *that* "first"  $\frac {x}{2x} =\frac {x}0 = \infty$ and $\infty \to \infty$ as $x^2 \to 0$ so $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac x{2x}= \lim_{\color{red}x\to 0}\lim_{\color{green}x \to 0}\frac {\color{red}x}{\color{green}{2x}}=\lim_{\color{red}x \to 0}\frac x{0}=\lim_{\color{green}x \to 0} \infty = \infty$.

But if we do them both "at the same time" we get $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac x{2x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac 12 = \frac 12$.

So which is it.  Well whenever we reduce $\color{red} x$ to so something small such as $\color{red}x = \delta$ then we must *also* reduce $\color{green}{2x}$ to something *equivalently* small such as $\color{green}{2x} = 2\delta$.  We can just make *one* of the small and leave the other one hanging around till we are ready for it.

So the first two are wrong.

.....

Okay.... you are asking "but what about the theorem that says if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = M$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = N$ then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)g(x) = MN$.  Isn't that actually saying we *can* do just said we *can't* do".

Welllll.... sort of.  But not really.  In this case $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = M$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) =N$ must actually *be* things where $MN$ is a value that makes sense.   If $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x) =\infty$ then "$0\cdot \infty$" is meaningless garbage and it doesn't make any sense to talk of it.

This is what we can "indeterminate form".

(*SUBTLE* thing to note:  When we say $\lim x f(x)g(x) = ML = \lim f(x)\lim g(x)$ we aren't "separating" the limits until *after* we get the result.  We are not taking the limits one after another, we are *still* playing with the limits both and the same time.  We just know ahead of time the result will hold. So we can *focus* on one of the other so long as we are aware the limits themselves are both occuring simultaneous.)

.....

Fortunately, for limits in *indeterminate* form we have l'hopitals rule.

If $\lim \frac {x}{1-\cos x}$ yiels $\frac {\lim x}{\lim (1-\cos x)} = \frac 00$ is in indeterminate form, we can sleep easy knowing

$\lim \frac {x}{1 - \cos x} = \lim\frac {derivative\ of\ x^2}{derivative\ of\ 1-\cos x} = \lim \frac {2x}{\sin x}= \frac {2}{1} = 2$.

Comment: "You can not EVER do that"... unless $f(x) = xg(x)$ and the limit of both $x$ and $g(x)$ exist.

Comment: Except you aren't actually *doing* that when you do that.  You aren't taking the limit of one of one with values of near $x$s and then taking the limit of the other with *different* near values of $x$.  You are finely tuning *one* copy of one value of $x$ and knowing that the two terms that will be producted are both being evaluated *simultaneously* you *AREN'T* doing that.  That's a different thing.

Comment: "unless f(x)=xg(x) and the limit of both x and g(x) exist. "  Not even then  Taking $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x\to a} f(x)\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ so long as $x$ is the single variable is *not* the samething as doing $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x) =\lim_{w\to a}f(w)\lim_{y\to a} g(y)$ which is essentially what the OP is attempting.

Comment: Could you please provide examples of two $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)$ are both real numbers, but that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)g(x) \neq \lim_{w \rightarrow a}f(w) \lim_{y \rightarrow a}f(y) $? Because that should just be a harmless change of notation.

Comment: I never said that the result isn't true.  I said the rationale and the method is not legitimate.

Comment: If it is true, why can one never use it?