# Find the limit of $\,\lim\limits_{\theta\to0} \frac{\theta^2}{1-\cos\theta}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, trigonometry

I'm learning how to evaluate limits of trigonometric functions. This is my attempt to solve $$\lim\limits_{\theta\to0} \dfrac{\theta^2}{1-\cos\theta}$$
The answer should be $2$. Can anyone confirm if I did it right?
If not, can you please explain me how to do it?

\begin{align*}
\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\theta^2}{1-\cos\theta}&=\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\theta^2}{1-\cos\theta} \\
&=\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\theta^2}{1-\cos\theta}\frac{1+\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta} \\
&=\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\theta^2(1+\cos\theta)}{1-\cos^2\theta} \\
&=\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\theta^2(1+\cos\theta)}{\sin^2\theta} \\
&=\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}\cdot\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}\cdot\frac{(1+\cos\theta)}{1} \\
&=\lim_{\theta\to0}\csc^2\theta\cdot(1+\cos\theta) \\
&=\lim_{\theta\to0}\csc^20\cdot(1+\cos0) \\
&=\lim_{\theta\to0}1+1=2 \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Write $\frac{{\theta ^2 }}{{\sin ^2 \theta }} = \left( {\frac{{\sin \theta }}{\theta }} \right)^{ - 2}$ and use the standard limit $\lim _{\theta  \to 0} \frac{{\sin \theta }}{\theta } = 1$. Note that $\csc\theta =\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$ and not $\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}$, and so $\csc\theta$ tends to $\pm \infty$ as $\theta \to 0$.

Comment: The step where you get $csc\theta^2$ is unclear, what happened to $\theta$? Maybe easier if you knew tew the limit of $\theta/\sin\theta$

Comment: You should really give some more context to which tools we are allowed to use: I can already think of two ("elementary") different ways to solve this problem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4081991/why-is-lim-x-to-0-fracx21-cosx-not-equal-to-0?noredirect=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your work is correct up to the step
$$\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\theta^2}{1 - \cos\theta} = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\theta}{\sin\theta} \cdot \frac{\theta}{\sin\theta} \cdot \frac{1 + \cos\theta}{1}$$
However, as Gary pointed out in the comments, $\csc\theta = \dfrac{1}{\sin\theta}$ rather than $\dfrac{\theta}{\sin\theta}$.

As Gary also pointed out in the comments,
$$\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} = 1$$
from which it follows that
$$\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\theta}{\sin\theta} = 1$$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\theta^2}{1 - \cos\theta} & = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\theta}{\sin\theta} \cdot \frac{\theta}{\sin\theta} \cdot \frac{1 + \cos\theta}{1}\\
& = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\theta}{\sin\theta} \cdot \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\theta}{\sin\theta} \cdot \lim_{\theta \to 0} (1 + \cos\theta)\\
& = 1 \cdot 1 \cdot (1 + 1)\\
& = 2
\end{align*}
Since
$$\lim_{\theta \to 0} \sin\theta = 0,$$
your work is also incorrect because
$$\lim_{\theta \to 0} \csc^2\theta = \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta} = \infty$$